# How to update page in django with foreignKey subject

Tags: python, django, django-forms, updates

I'm new to django, I'm trying to update a page with foreignkey to subject. Here is my code

models.py

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank = False)
    visible = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    position = models.IntegerField()
    date_published = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Page(models.Model):
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank = False)
    description = models.TextField()
    thumbs = models.ImageField(blank = True)
    visible = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    position = models.IntegerField()
    date_published = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, auto_now=False)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('dashboard/', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
    re_path(r'^dashboard/edit/(?P<subject_slug>[\w-]+)/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)', views.edit_article, name='edit_page'),
]
```

views.py

```
def edit_article(request, subject_slug, slug):

    subject = Subject.objects.get(slug = subject_slug)
    article = subject.page_set.get(slug = slug)
    form = ArticleForm(request.POST or None, instance = article)

    if request == request.POST:
        form = ArticleForm(request.POST, instance = article)

        if form.is_valid():
            c = form.save( commit = False)
            c = subject
            c.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/dashboard/')

    context = {
        'title' : article.title,
        'article' : article,
        'form':form
        }

    return render(request, 'dashboard/editarticle.html', context)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Subject, Page, NewsFeed
class ArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Page
        fields = ['title','slug','description','thumbs', 'visible','position']
```

article.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Edit article</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">

</head>
<body>
    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
    <form  method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }} 
    <input type ='submit' value='submit'/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

When I'm trying to save the form the views wont redirect and the page wont update, can you guys enlighten me on how to achieved the task of updating the page.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
def my_view(request):
    ...
    return redirect('/some/url/')
```

> Reference https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/shortcuts/

Comment: I already tried that, my main issue here is I cannot update the page. Is there anyway to update the page by using the forms.py

Answer (score 0):

Try to print the article that you are getting from slug, if it is getting the article then simply assign

`form = ArticleForm(instance = article)`

Now you will have a initialized form with previous values.

One more suggestion, try to use django class base view. Still have any doubts comment it.

Comment: don't  pass `request.POST` in form, simply pass`instance = article`.